# Custom navigation transition with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, navigation

I'm used to building custom transitions between `UIViewController`'s using `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`. Is there an analog in SwiftUI? I know there are some ways to do animation in SwiftUI. In iOS 14 you can even use `matchedGeometryEffect` to animate one view to another. But these solutions don't seem to allow you to change the default push/pop animation and morph one view into another (such as the iOS Photos app animation: grid view photo -> detail view photo).

Comment: your question is about animation on changing View to another View?